# Bootstrap tooltip function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've downloaded and used a bootstrap theme. The theme's demo can be found on:
http://www.blacktie.co/demo/dashgum/

In the theme, the index.html file references the following js files:

```
<script src="~/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<script src="~/assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>
```

in common-scripts.js, the following line can be found:

```
$('.tooltips').tooltip();
```

When I debug, I see that the jQuery statement: `$('.tooltips')` works well (returns results) but it seems as though the tooltip() function is not found and called on any of them. The result is that no tooltip is shown.

**An example of a tooltip that is shown on the demo but not on my local website:**

The HTML code found on index.html:

```
<div class="fa fa-bars tooltips" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Toggle Navigation"></div>
```

[image: Result on the demo but not on my local machine]

Comment: you get any error in console when hovering over the non-working div?

Comment: On chrome, tooltips just work fine for me.

Comment: @PraveenPuglia the OP didn't share their site, the pasted link is the demo site of the theme, so of course it works there :)

Comment: I took my upvote down: we need an error message. If tooltip doesn't work, it should be reflected in dev tools and should show an error...

Comment: @webeno : there's no error... it just doesn't respond or do anything.

Comment: so you see absolutely no error, not even the resources (like bootstrap.js or common scripts.js) missing, nothing, but when you hover over that div, it does nothing at all? if you're sure you copied all files and folders from the theme, and the html looks exactly identical as on the demo, and you have no error in console, then this is a strange situation... to me at least... is this happening on a test site or on a sever? if on a server, can you share the link to it?

Comment: I saw some comment from you, but you seem to have deleted it: something like you copied a blank index.html file...?

Comment: @webeno Sorry, I just realized I wasn't accurate. I've copied the theme's blank.html file and not the index.html file. In the blank.html file in the demo, the tooltip also doesn't work! 
http://www.blacktie.co/demo/dashgum/blank.html
Can you spot the mistake of the theme's developer? Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at the console, it errors at `customSelect()` - though this function call only comes after `custom-scripts.js`, it may be the culprit... try removing or fixing this line in your version, and see if it changes anything...

Comment: ...this is most probably the cause, as all other pages, where there is no console error, are displaying the tooltip fine...

Comment: I was lying: http://www.blacktie.co/demo/dashgum/form_component.html displays the tooltip too but it shows the same error in console...

Comment: I've tried to remove the customSelect() line but it still doesn't work :/ probably a unrelated error.

If the tooltip works on index.html but not on blank.html, probably a js file reference that is found on index.html file and not on blank.html is the problem, isn't it?

Comment: like I said in my previous note, my assumption appears to have been incorrect, not sure what's causing this, not long until I lose my patience trying to figure this out... :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErvgV4P6Fzc
(Guns N' Roses - Patience, music video :-) )

Comment: lol, I lost it, it's gone... :) sorry, dude, try pushing this over to the theme author, or just try copying everything that's on another site where it works, and, one by one, remove stuff from it, then test in-between removals...

Comment: OK, Thanks for trying :-)
I will probably push it over to the theme author, I bought the premium theme

Comment: fa fa-bars tooltips? its obviously a font awesome class. Import the font awesome css and you'll be sorted  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> If it can't find the associated class, of course it'll return an error

Comment: @RachelGallen 
the font awesome css was already imported ...
tooltip() function (which cannot be found)  is supposed to be a bootstrap function